# Create a report with unique country names and total number of unique countries

Tags: reporting

How do I create a report with the unique countries that exist for all users? So that the Grand Total represents the unique number of countries.

In other words 'I want the total number of unique countries'

Answer (score 2):

The 'Power of One' formula may help

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkCLAAY

> Create a custom field on each of the objects (I would do this on every
>   object you use in SFDC).
>
> Field Name: whatever you want Datatype: Formula  Result:  Number,0
>   decimal Formula:  1  (that's it, just a number 1)
>
> now add these custom fields to your report and Summarize(Sum) them. 
>   You'll get the count of distinct records for each object.

**Important Note: If you use this you owe SteveMo a frigging beer.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can count distinct values of a column in SF reports. If you could export to Excel then you could just 'dedupe' the column of country values and then do a count of the # of rows.

If your SF version allows Apex code, you could do a SOQL query to count distinct values and store those results in a custom field on the User object.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing. I'm exporting to excel and using 'remove duplicates'. I can probably write an APEX code to do that, but then I need to create an object to store it in, and I don't see a place for such an object. But it is very possible. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Before you dive into apex - have you considered [Analytic Snapshots](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm)? You'd still need a helper custom object to store your results but well, better than writing code (which might be an one-off thing, might have to be a batch job if you have > 10K users...)

Alternatively you would have to make a Country custom object and write code that creates/finds & links the user to Country on every insert & update. Probably not worth doing...